# UWP WebViews to use multiple profiles

Tags: webview, uwp

I have a scenario, when my user wants to sign into two different accounts. Unfortunately, the API does not support that (e.g. it logs off account 1 when logging into account 2). API uses a WebView-based auth.

Is there a way I could create a WebView, and make it have a separate profile? E.g. each app embedding WebView has its own profile, but can I have multiple WebView profiles in my single app?

I am actually doing that in a desktop bridge app so far, so I can start a separate process if necessary.

Comment: Have you checked the [Web account management sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WebAccountManagement)? It seemed that you want.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT, this seems unrelated. It talks about Microsoft managed accounts. In my case accounts are provided by a third-party web service, where user must login with a WebView.

Comment: Ok. For now, there's no built-in API for you to do it. You could submit a "Feature Request" on [WPDev UserVoice](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/).

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT, done so https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/34424878-multiple-profiles-in-webview

Comment: Ok. That's good.